# A combinatorial proof of Wilson's theorem [Proof Verification]

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to prove the non-trivial assertion of Wilson's theorem,

> If $p$ is a prime, $p$ divides $(p-1)! - (p-1)$.

I'm going to consider the set of $p$-cycles on $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, which I'll denote $C_p$. Now, $C_p$ has size $(p-1)!$ for the following reason: it suffices to choose the images of $1,,...,p$ without repeating values or having fixed points, therefore we have $p-1$ options for the image of $1$, $p-2$ for the image of $2$, and so on until we get to the image of $p$, which is at this point already determined. Now, let's observe that if $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, the translation given by summing $a$,

$$
\tau_a : \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p
\\ x \ \mapsto a + x 
$$

is an element of $C_p$ with inverse $\tau_{-a}$.

We can then define the set $X_p = C_p - \{\tau_a : a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}\}$ with $|X| = (p-1)! - (p-1)$, and the following equivalence relation on $X_p$:

$$
f \sim g \iff f = \tau_{-a}\cdot g\cdot \tau_a, \ \text{ for some } a \in \mathbb{Z}_p
$$

If we can conclude that each equivalence class on $X_p/\sim$ has size $p$, this will imply that $p \ | \ |X_p| = (p-1)! - (p-1)$ as we claim. It is clear that if $f \in \mathbb{S}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$,

$$
[f] \subseteq \{\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot \tau_a : a \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}
$$

To finish, it will be sufficient to see the other inclusion, that is, that for any $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the element $\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot \tau_a$ is not a translation and therefore is in $X_p$ (the fact that $\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot \tau_a \sim f$ is immediate). Let's suppose that, on the contrary, there exists $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ such that

$$
\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot \tau_a \equiv \tau_b
$$

and therefore

$$
f \equiv \tau_a\cdot \tau_b \cdot \tau_{-a} \equiv \tau_b
$$

since translation commute. We've reached then a contradiction, since $f$ cannot be a translation, so in effect each class is as previously described and has size $p$, which concludes the proof.

Is this correct? I'd also appreciate any suggestions to simplify the argument. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've noticed that it is also necessary to see that the set $\{\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot \tau_a : a \in \mathbb{Z}_p\}$ has in fact $p$ *distinct* elements. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't checked this in detail but the idea makes sense to me.  I bet it can be simplified with some group theory.

Comment: Perhaps I should've also said that I'm trying not to use any additional machinery (I'm aware that group theory makes this result much more direct).

Comment: Actually the group theory is already implicit: Think about why this does not work for $p$ composite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks correct, and the set $\{\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot\tau_{a}:a\in\Bbb{Z}/(p)\}$ does have $p$ distinct elements, since if $\tau_{-a}\cdot f\cdot\tau_{a} = \tau_{-b}\cdot f\cdot\tau_{b}$ then $f = \tau_{b-a}\cdot f\cdot\tau_{a-b}$ implying $a-b=0$ and thus $a=b$.

This last bit is because when looking at only $p$ letters the only permutations on $p$ letters that  $p$ cycle commutes with are its powers.  And the powers of $\tau_{a-b}$ are all the translations, and $f$ is not a translation.

To see the claim: conjugation by $\sigma$ takes a cycle $(abc...)$ to $(\sigma(a)\sigma(b)\sigma(c)...)$.  You can see that there are only $p$ ways this can be the original cycle, so only $p$ possible $\sigma$s do the trick, and we already know the $p$ powers of the original cycle are among them, so nothing else can work.

Comment: What I'm stuck on is on the fact that $\tau_{-(a+b)}f\tau_{a+b} \equiv f$ implies $a = b$.

Comment: It doesn't....if i had derived that first equality you give, it would imply $a=-b$.  But the first equality you state is wrong.  Please reread.

Comment: My bad, I meant the equality you stated, I still don't see how the implication is direct. Would you mind detailing this step?

Comment: Done. See the new edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful. Cheers.

Comment: It's actually quite interesting that this is the obstruction to proving the (false) statement that $n$ divides $(n-1)!-\phi(n)$ for $n$ composite.  The proof would almost work, except for some translations being powers of non-translation $n$-cycles, which messes everything up.

Comment: I see, that's really interesting. Again, thanks so much for your input!